# Girl enters a competition to go to space, ship gets sucked into a wormhole

Tags: story-identification, books

The book is about a girl who enters a competition to go into space

- One of the tests was a colour test and they also had to go in one of those spinning things
- The woman running the competition was very rich

The ship was called the *Adventurer*

- They went past Jupiter
- They stopped at a re-fueling station they had to space walk to get into; there was wine

They get sucked into some sort of wormhole which is making everything younger

- Everybody was told that the ship was new but the ship doesn't start getting 'younger' for a couple of years worth of 'youngening'
- There was a really young clever boy talking about Schrödinger's cat

Comment: Is this a young adult novel?

Comment: Well time frame starts from 1935 onwards then.. Can you narrow it down any :)

Comment: @Dreamwalker wormholes were only named so in 1957.